# How can I kill all child processes when exiting from my shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, csh

I've got a C shell script that runs a program. That program spawns off a child. When I send a SIGINT to my shell script via ctrl-C, the shell script exits as well as the process that it spawned I think. However, the last process remains. How can I instruct C shell to kill all child processes before it exits then?

Comment: Why are you writing scripts in C shell? It's the worse shell for scripting. http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/

Comment: Yes I'm aware that it's a horrible "language"

Comment: I (mercifully) haven't had C shell installed in years (specifically tcsh), but maybe try engaging hang up (`stty hupcl`) then a `kill -6 $$`?

Comment: It sounds like the problem is with the program not killing its child, not your script.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a signal trap for SIGINT? [See the Interrupt Handling section here](http://parallel.vub.ac.be/documentation/linux/unixdoc_download/Scripts.html):

```
#!/bin/csh

# Setup sigint handler
onintr close

# start a background process
sleep 1000&
setenv pid $!

while (1 == 1)
  echo Program is running
  sleep 2
end

close:
echo End of program. Kill $pid
kill $pid
```